# MYSQL Query show only Open cases online

Tags: php, mysql

I have an ***MYSQL*** query I need to only display **Open Cases** the open status is in another table so I need to link **History.sid** to **Client.ref**

The table looks like  **Client** which has fields **ref** and **statusRB** which statusRB shows **Open** and **Closed** and then **History** which has **sid** which is same id number as **ref**

So i need to find a way a lining sid to ref before it displays the results of only **Open cases**

```
$query = mysql_query("select FROM_UNIXTIME(a.maxepoch,\"%d-%m-%Y\"),  b.id, b.sid, b.did,  b.type, b.nextaction, FROM_UNIXTIME(b.nextactiondate,\"%d-%m-%Y\") from History b,
(select  max(epoch) as maxepoch  from History
group by did) a
#where a.maxepoch = b.epoch and b.epoch < (unix_timestamp(now()) - 2592000)
Where a.maxepoch = b.epoch and b.epoch < (unix_timestamp(now()) - 604800)
order by b.epoch desc");


  $mydate = date("d-m-Y");

  $message = "<br><br><h1>30 day Report for $mydate</h1><br>";

  $message .= "<table border=\"1\"><tr><strong><td>Customer Ref</td><td>Client Ref</td><td>Action</td><td>Action Date</td><td>Next Action</td><td>Next Action Date</td></strong></tr>";

  while ($def = mysql_fetch_row($query)) {

    $sid = $def[2];
    $did = $def[3];
    $type = $def[4];
    $nextaction = $def[5];
    $nextactiondate = $def[6];
    $maxepoch = $def[0];
```

Comment: I have accepted the other ones ?

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do. A schema of your table + sample data + expected resultset would be helpful.